# What is the difference in stripe's client and server?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement some sample code from Stripe's official github page but I am confused as to what the difference is between the client and server folder. I am interested in **Payment Element** and not **Checkout**.

The client folder has index.html file (client->html->index.html) where there is "Pay now" button.

The server folder also has and index.php file (server->php->index.php) where there is "Pay" button.

Link to [github](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-payment/tree/main/payment-element)

Comment: It looks like Client might be anything customer-facing (web pages, view, iOS app), while Server is anything backend that would take the customer's information and use it to contact Stripe. But you might want to email the maintainer for clarification

Comment: @aynber But why would there be a "buy" button? Is it just to test it without using the front-end?

Comment: You'd have to ask the maintainers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code [repo](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-payment/tree/main/payment-element) you are referencing is covering all the programming languages that Stripe has client libraries for and not all of the server-side integrations are built the same.  The separation between `client` and `server` in these examples are where the code is intended to run, client-side (browser) or server-side (web server).

Stripe uses 2 separate [API Keys](https://stripe.com/docs/keys) to authenticate your API requests.  The [Publishable Key](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#obtain-api-keys) is intended to be used on the `client` side with [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/js) while the [Secret Key](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#obtain-api-keys) should only ever be used on a server.  This is because client-side code runs in your users browsers where they ultimately can control and modify that code.  The Publishable Key has much less access and cannot really do anything *on it's own*.  The Secret Key has full access to all the [Stripe APIs](https://stripe.com/docs/api).  This is why you only deploy the Secret Key in the `/server` code which runs on a server that **you** control.

The `index.php` is returning a server-rendered HTML document so we see less separation between `server` and `client`.  But if you look at the `node` or `python` servers you will see in those cases the `server` code, for the most part, is functioning as a REST API.  In that case the separation between the `client` and `server` code is a bit more obvious.  You could have your `server` code running on one host while your `client` code is served from another host.

If you wanted to test this out, you could spin up one local dev server running on one port (e.g. `4242`) hosting your `server` code and then run a separate dev server on another port (e.g. `8080`) and host your `client` code.  However I don't think it is required for the PHP integration since that uses PHP's ability to run server code and return rendered HTML in the same file.

Comment: Yea, that makes a lot of sense. Because php can run server code and create html in the same file, one could combine the client and server function together. So that means for php, I wouldn't even need to use the client folder in this case?